# printing characters which match a persons age, using for loops

Tags: java, netbeans

I want to make a code that will print:

`Andy      **
 Kristy    **********
 Amy       *****`

I want the program to print * for how old the person is. I would also like to be able to change the ages and still get correct code. The code I have written below will only print out

`Andy       *
 Kristy     *
 Amy        *`

how do I change my for loop to achieve this?

```
public static void main(String[] args){

  String name = "Andy";
  int age = 2;
  drawChart(name, age);
  name = "Kristy";
  age = 10;
  drawChart(name, age);
  name = "Amy";
  age = 5;
  drawChart(name, age);

public static void drawChart(String name, int age){



     for(int i = age; i <= age; i++){

        System.out.println("*");

     }

  }
```

Comment: Your loop starts at `int i = age`. Looks like that should be `int i = 1`

Answer (score 1):

Your for-loop is invalid. You need to set `i = 1`, or even change it to something like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<age; i++) {
    System.our.print("*");
}
// Also add new line after printing all stars, not for each star
System.out.println("");
```

Good luck

Comment: It is valid, but don't do what is needed. Invalid feel like it would not compile (my feeling though)

Comment: You are probably right, I might to use different word to describe the problem with variables in loop.

Answer (score 1):

Change the method to:

```
    public static void drawChart(String name, int age){


        System.out.print(name+": ");
         for(int i = 0; i < age; i++){

            System.out.print("*");

         }
         System.out.println();
    }
```

First print the name and the stars and at the end the newline.
And for sure your for Loop arguments makes no sence.

Because:
it starts at 2 and runs until 2 <=2

```
for(int i = age; i <= age; i++){
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
 for(int i = age; i <= age; i++){
    System.out.print("*");
 }
```

To:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < age; i++){
    System.out.print("*");
 }
```

Your current loop starts at 'age' instead of 0 making it only go one iteration.

Comment: print not println

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems in your loop,
Please see my comments below

```
    for(int i = age; i <= age; i++){ --> Loop should start with i=1
        System.out.println("*"); // You should use print to avoid new line
     }
     // After this Loop add a blank println statement to add a new line
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in the for loop.

Change it as follows:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= age; i++) {
    System.out.print("*");           // Remove println here 
}
// Go to next line outside the loop
System.out.println("");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the problem in the other answers, but I like to provide some nice alternative. Some could say it would not be good for performance but I like the small codes ;)

You could use the `String.format` method to do it.

```
public static String getAge(int age){
    return String.format("%" + n + "s","").replace(" ", "*");
}
```

This will simply create a String with `age` number of space then replace them with a `*`.